# How can I develop a web client gtalk via xmpp

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I try to develop a web client gtalk in my http server.I know what I should do is just using the strophe.js which could send the xmpp message to xmpp server. I don't want to build my own xmpp server which connect to gtalk xmpp server.I think it may no need to build xmpp server as a transport.
But the gtalk xmpp server has no http-binding,so what should I do to send my http message to gtalk xmpp server? And if I send the http message to talk.google.com:5222,will it reply to me? Is it possible to make the connection between me and gtalk xmpp server?
I need your help.Thanks!

Comment: Can you use the XMPP service on Google App Engine? http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtalk server does not run a BOSH connection manager, so you would have to use a standalone one, like Punjab, for example.

After installing and running Punjab, you can have a HTTP-Bind at http://localhost:5280/xmpp-httpbind. Use your Strophe with it.